# Having trouble recognizing libxml in distribution build

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I'm having trouble compiling with libxml in my project, but only on my distribution build. I've been careful to copy the header search paths and library search paths from my debug distribution where it compiles just fine. Here's what I have:

Header Search Paths

usr/include/libxml2

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/usr/include/libxml2

Library Search Paths
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/usr/include/libxml2

Other Linker Flags

-lxml2

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in header search path $(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2 (although it would point to /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/usr/include/libxml2) and Recursive box checked

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yeah, that worked! I was going to do that but I looked for the file in the path and couldn't see any difference.

Comment: Glad!! ( Please don't forget to accept this as an answer if it is )